# SQL Left Join Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone please help resolve an issue, I am left joining two CTE's?

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'left'.

Query:

```
   with Cte_LatestPatInfo as

    (select max(a.LogID) as LastPatRec, p.unitnum, p.PatNum, a.iplan from         rrscsql2.arhighdollar.dbo.tblarinfoHistory a
    inner join rrscsql2.arhighdollar.dbo.tblPatInfoHistory p
    on a.patID=p.patID and a.LogID=p.LogID
    where a.Active = 1
    and a.ReasonCode is not null
    group by  p.unitnum, p.PatNum, a.iplan)

    select *,rc.Description from  rrscsql2.arhighdollar.dbo.tblPatInfoHistory p
    inner join cte_LatestPatInfo li
    on p.PatNum=li.PatNum and p.UnitNum=li.UnitNum and p.LogID = li.LastPatRec
    inner join  rrscsql2.arhighdollar.dbo.tblarinfoHistory ah 
    on ah.LogID=p.LogID and ah.iplan = li.iplan and p.PatID=ah.PatID
    left join rrscsql2.ARHighDollar.dbo.tblReasonCodes rc 
    on ah.ReasonCode=rc.ReasonCode,

    cte_EOMDenials as
    (select d.* from rrscsql2.Denials.dbo.tblDenialMonthEnd d 
    Inner join rrscsql3.Facilities.dbo.vwFacilities f
    on d.UnitNum = f.UnitNum and f.Owner like '%LifePoint%'
    Inner join rrscsql2.Denials.dbo.tblDispositionDictionary t
    on d.disposition=t.disposition and DispositionType like'O%'
    Where datediff(mm, monthending, GETDATE()) = 1
    and DATEDIFF(mm,DischDate,monthending)>2)
    left join cte_EOMDenials d
    on p.unitnum=d.unitnum and p.patnum = d.patnum and p.insplan=d.iplan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to introduce *all* of your `CTE`s first via a single `WITH`, and then you can use them in a final query:

```
with Cte_LatestPatInfo as

(select max(a.LogID) as LastPatRec, p.unitnum, p.PatNum, a.iplan from
     rrscsql2.arhighdollar.dbo.tblarinfoHistory a
inner join rrscsql2.arhighdollar.dbo.tblPatInfoHistory p
on a.patID=p.patID and a.LogID=p.LogID
where a.Active = 1
and a.ReasonCode is not null
group by  p.unitnum, p.PatNum, a.iplan),

cte_EOMDenials as
(select d.* from rrscsql2.Denials.dbo.tblDenialMonthEnd d 
Inner join rrscsql3.Facilities.dbo.vwFacilities f
on d.UnitNum = f.UnitNum and f.Owner like '%LifePoint%'
Inner join rrscsql2.Denials.dbo.tblDispositionDictionary t
on d.disposition=t.disposition and DispositionType like'O%'
Where datediff(mm, monthending, GETDATE()) = 1
and DATEDIFF(mm,DischDate,monthending)>2)

select *,rc.Description from  rrscsql2.arhighdollar.dbo.tblPatInfoHistory p
inner join cte_LatestPatInfo li
on p.PatNum=li.PatNum and p.UnitNum=li.UnitNum and p.LogID = li.LastPatRec
inner join  rrscsql2.arhighdollar.dbo.tblarinfoHistory ah 
on ah.LogID=p.LogID and ah.iplan = li.iplan and p.PatID=ah.PatID
left join rrscsql2.ARHighDollar.dbo.tblReasonCodes rc 
on ah.ReasonCode=rc.ReasonCode
left join cte_EOMDenials d
on p.unitnum=d.unitnum and p.patnum = d.patnum and p.insplan=d.iplan
```

Comment: Query is now running and we have a result set. Great learning experience, thank you so much.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever To my knowledge, you only introduce the first one with "WITH", thereafter it is simply ", CTENAME AS(), CTENAME2() etc."

Comment: That's why I said "a single `WITH`"

Answer (score 0):

The statement does not seem to join two CTEs. If you want to join two ctes you can achieve it like the following example

```
;WITH CTE_1
as
( select field1, field2... from sometable),
CTE_2 
as
(select field1, field2... from sometable),
select  a.field1, a.field2, b.field1, b.field2 
from CTE_1 a left join CTE_2 b on a.field1 = b.field1;
```

You will notice that the two ctes were defined first, separated by comma(,) then use in the select statement.

Please see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for reference.